# iOS 7 NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, json, xcode

I am trying to develop an app that parses json data. I have the following json :

```
{
   myobject:[
     {
       id:184,
       title: "test title"
     }    
   ]
}
```

I have the following code which im trying to get the title data from this json

```
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *currentObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }

    NSDictionary *nar = [currentObject objectForKey:@"myobject"];

    NSLog(@"%@",[nar valueForKey:@"title"]);

    NSString *curTitle = [nar valueForKey:@"title"];
    self.myTitle.text = curTitle;
```

When I log the title, I can see that the title is indeed coming back. However, when I try to set the myTitle.text I get the following error

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15631850`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is crash because Your dictionary contain `NSArray`, not dictionary.

```
NSArray *ar = [currentObject objectForKey:@"myobject"];

for(NSDictionary *dict in ar)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"title"];
)

}

 NSString *curTitle = [[ar objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"title"];
 self.myTitle.text = curTitle;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your json my object field is not a dictionary, but array of dictionaries, so `[nar valueForKey:@"title"]` will return array of valueForKey for each of elements in that array.

If you're sure about data format you can extract string value from it the following way:

```
 NSArray *nar = [currentObject objectForKey:@"myobject"];
 NSString *curTitle = nar[0][@"title"];
```

But of course it is better to add some data validation/error handling in production code.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign `NSArray` to `self.myTitle.text`.

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];

NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *currentObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
if(error)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}

NSArray *nar = [currentObject objectForKey:@"myobject"];
NSString *title = [[nar objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"title"];
NSLog(@"%@",title);
self.myTitle.text = title;
```